# how to Create ODBC Connection from Access to SQL Server using link server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I am create odbc for access db

[Odbc access database file like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ7Fa.png)

when i try to create link server in sql ,unable to connect.IS IT POSSIBLE TO CONNECT THROUGH link server

[Link server-see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ylCc.png)

When i use below query it created successfully and tested,but i can't use access db and sql at same time.
Error :File in use

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server='TIMES',
@srvproduct='TIMES',
@provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
 @datasrc=N'C:\Program Files\xxxx\aaa.mdb' 



exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='TIMES', 
@useself='false', 
@rmtuser='Admin', 
@rmtpassword=''
```

could any help to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
#1)  ODBC Database (create link to SQL Server)

#2)  Open the link and view your Information_Schema (or whatever you want) in SQL Server.
```

[image]

[image]